# How to "close" a chat room

Tags: support, chat

5 days ago, as an experiment, I clicked on the link that appeared on a comment thread (the one that says "let us continue this discussion in chat").

The system created a chat room for the thread, and copied comments there. Wonderful.

But now the room is useless (I said it was an experiment), so: how can I close/delete/remove/whatever that room? It "disappears" by itself when not used for enough days, or a manual action is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will [happen automatically](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) in one of two ways, depending on the previous activity in the room.

- If the room seems to have some interesting content (see the above link for a precise definition), it will be *frozen* after 14 days of silence. This means it's hidden from the regular room list (you have to explicitly "show frozen rooms" to see it), and new messages can't be added.
- If the room does not really seem to have interesting content, it will be *deleted* after seven days of silence. Deleting is similar to deletion of questions and answers on the Q&A sites: Only users with more than 10,000 reputation can see it; new messages can't be added.

Manual freezing and deletion is limited to moderators. If you feel strongly that a room should disappear immediately, just find a moderator to do it, but usually you can just wait and the inactive room will disappear eventually.

Comment: DOH! And I've browsed thru the FAQ! Two times! Thanks...